# Can't export or list keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm using my desktop to obtain files from a server (using git and rsync), now I want to use my notebook and try therefore to export/import the required RSA-keys.

Automatic login from the notebook to the desktop is enabled and works fine.

Edit:
To specify:
There is the Desktop (A) which can connect to the Server (B) without any password.
With my Notebook (C) I can connect to the Desktop (A) but not to the Server (B).

Now I would like to export the keys of the desktop (A) to my notebook (C) so I can connect to the server (B).

On the desktop (A) I see the key of my desire:

```
mario@desktop:~$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
4096 xx:xx:xx:yy:yy:yy:zz:zz:zz:xy:yz:xz:yx:zy:zx:xx  mario@desktop (RSA)
```

The files are there too:

```
mario@desktop:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh/*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mario mario 1147 Mai 30 12:48 /home/mario/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 mario mario 3243 Apr 11 16:30 /home/mario/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 mario mario  741 Apr 11 16:30 /home/mario/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 mario mario  444 Apr 11 16:32 /home/mario/.ssh/known_hosts
-rw------- 1 mario mario 1766 Mai 15 12:35 /home/mario/.ssh/notebookID
-rw-r--r-- 1 mario mario  397 Mai 15 12:35 /home/mario/.ssh/notebookID.pub
```

Strangely those commands don't have any output at all:

```
mario@desktop:~$ gpg --list-keys
mario@desktop:~$ gpg --list-secret-keys
```

I wonder, there should be at least the public key from my notebook be listed.

Attempts to list or export keys fail:

```
mario@desktop:~$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
mario@desktop:~$ gpg --export --output public-keys.asc
gpg: WARNUNG: Nothing exported
mario@desktop:~$ gpg --export-secret-keys --output secret-keys.asc
gpg: WARNUNG: Nothing exported
mario@desktop:~$ gpg --export-secret-key secring.gpg
gpg: WARNUNG: Nothing exported
```

The agent works:

```
mario@desktop:~$ ssh-agent 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xxfgqbw7SnZe/agent.5801; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=5802; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 5802;
```

The first error looks promising to search on the internet. Stackoverflow provides some answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/48868

The suggested solution with eval is not really improving things:

```
mario@desktop:~$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 5849
mario@desktop:~$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

What am I doing wrong..? I'm out of ideas.
Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "exporting my public keys" ? in ssh paradigm, files in *.pub are you public keys. thay are mainly used in authorized_keys to allow incomming ssh/scp/sftp connection. thoses keys can't sign document, or allow https connection.

Comment: @Archemar - so how should I move those to my notebook to connect to the server?

Comment: simply `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (notebookID.pub ?) from starting host and user to `authorized_keys` in destination host and user. (this is a single line to be copied/transfered)

Comment: @Archemar `notebookID.pub` is the key I exchanged to connect from my notebook to the desktop without the login.

Comment: After you `eval $(ssh-agent)`, you need to add identities, _e.g._ `ssh-add notebookID`.

Comment: @user4556274 Ok, did - no error message came, yet I still can't export any keys to my notebook. But why should I add the notebookID? My notebook has that key already. I assume it should be `id_rsa`. Tried both, no changes, but now `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` have the same output.

Comment: Nowhere in your question to you specify exactly what you are trying to do, other than "I want to use my notebook".  To connect from machine **A** to machine **B** with an ssh key managed via ssh-agent, you need (1) ssh-agent running on **A** (2) a private key loaded in the ssh-agent on **A** (3) an authorized_keys file on **B** containing the public key corresponding to the private key on **A**.  (4) gpg keys are a completely separate matter.

Comment: @user4556274 - I edited it, is it more clear now?

Comment: Append the notebook key to the server's `authorized_keys` file:  `notebook$ ssh-copy-id qohelet@server`.  The desktop keys shouldn't need to come into it.  You already have the desktop key on the server; now you also want the laptop key on the server.  (?)

Comment: @user4556274 - that's the problem. I can't even connect with the notebook (C) to the server (B). I don't know much about its configuration and usually just withdraw files files using git or rsync. Can't I just export the keys from the desktop (A) to my notebook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59738/discussion-between-user4556274-and-qohelet).

Answer (score 1):

First, you are mixing commands for two entirely unrelated programs. Even though they both rely on the same cryptographic algorithms, OpenSSH and GnuPG (PGP) have their own key types and independent storage.

An exception would be if you used gpg-agent's SSH agent emulation. But you're not using that – you're using the stock OpenSSH agent.

Therefore `gpg` *is not supposed to* list any SSH keys for you. Just copy `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/notebookID` (and their associated .pub files) by hand, using scp, sftp, &c.

---

Second, ssh-agent has nothing to do with exporting keys either. It can hold your keys in memory for the purpose of *using* them in SSH, but it won't let you export them back *anyway.* (It also does not automatically load keys, you must ssh-add them every time.)

So in this case you don't *need* `ssh-add -l` to list anything or even work. Just copy the files by hand.

*(Again, the above does not necessarily apply to gpg-agent's "SSH agent emulation".)*

Comment: I copied them already. That was the first thing I tried, no success

Comment: No success with what – ssh? rsync? So far you only said you _wanted_ to export them to your notebook, but haven't demonstrated anything on it – the post only shows unrelated commands on the _desktop._

Comment: I used `tar -zcvf sshs.tgz .ssh/` to pack all the keys on the desktop (A), used `scp` from my notebook (C) to obtain them and just did a `gunzip sshs.tgz` in my home folder. Then I tried to use git and rsync from the notebook (C) to obtain the files from the server (B).

Comment: Which one of the two keys were you expecting it to use? (By default it'll only use id_rsa, or agent keys if any.) Have you tried plain `ssh` to the server? (Adding -v would show what it tried.)

Comment: @user4556274 suggested that already. On the desktop (A) things work fine. On the notebook it fails... See: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59738/discussion-between-user4556274-and-qohelet